# Fluentd : Is there a way to add multiple tags in single match block

Tags: logging, fluentd, fluent-bit

I have multiple source with different tags.
Im trying to add multiple tags inside single match block like this.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @label @TESTLABEL
  path /var/log/containers/app-one-*.log
  pos_file /var/log/app-one.log.pos
  tag app.one
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
  read_from_head true
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  @label @TESTLABEL
  path /var/log/containers/app-two-*.log
  pos_file /var/log/app-two.log.pos
  tag app.two
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
  read_from_head true
</source>

<source>
  @type tail
  @label @TESTLABEL
  path /var/log/containers/app-three-*.log
  pos_file /var/log/app-three.log.pos
  tag app.three
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
  read_from_head true
</source>

<label @TESTLABEL>
  <match app.*>
    @type Test(confidential so adding test)
    subsystemname ${tag_parts[1]}
    is_json true
  </match>
</label>
```

Trying to set subsystemname value as tag's sub name like(one/two/three).
${tag_prefix[1]} is not working for me. Not sure if im doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use whitespace `<match tag1 tag2 tagN>`
From [official docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#how-do-the-match-patterns-work)
When multiple patterns are listed inside a single tag (delimited by one or more whitespaces), it matches any of the listed patterns:

- The patterns  match a and b
- The patterns <match a.** b.*> match a, a.b, a.b.c (from the first pattern) and b.d (from the second pattern).